# Why is there no Seq.partition in F#

Tags: f#

In F# we have `List.partition` and `Array.partition` which return a tuple of lists and a tuple of arrays respectively.

so, why is there no `Seq.partition` returning a tuple of sequences?

here is a very simple implementation:
[F# Snippets](http://fssnip.net/snippet/4K/0)

so... why isn't this part of the core?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In F# 4.0 (Visual Studio 2015), the core libraries are a lot more uniform than before, but they still do not come with an implementation of `Seq.partition`. You can find more about this in the F# language design discussion: [Regular functional operators producing two or more output collections](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/ListSeqArrayAdditions.md#regular-functional-operators-producing-two-or-more-output-collections).

The summary is that the `Seq.partition` function is quite tricky and a having it could introduce potential performance issues. There a couple of ways it can work:

- It can iterate over the input collection twice (like the FsSnip version), which can cause issues if you have complex delayed computation (you're doing everything twice)
- It can iterate over the input once, but then it would have to do some complex mutable state sharing (which could secretly allocate memory).

So, `Seq.partition` cannot be implemented reasonably while keeping all the good properties that you would expect about the `seq<'T>` type.

Comment: But `Seq.partition` is basically just a specialized version of `Seq.groupBy`, which already addresses the issues you raised. So, since we have the latter, we could just implement the former as a wrapper around it without creating any additional concerns. See my suggested implementation below.

Answer (score 7):

`Seq.partition` is just a specialized version of `Seq.groupBy`, so the standard library could implement the former as a wrapper around the latter without introducing any new issues.

```
let partition predicate source =
    let map =
        source
            |> Seq.groupBy predicate
            |> Map.ofSeq
    let get flag =
        map
            |> Map.tryFind flag
            |> Option.defaultValue Seq.empty
    get true, get false
```