# How to split a sequence in F# based on another sequence in an idiomatic way

Tags: f#, sequences

I have, in F#, 2 sequences, each containing distinct integers, strictly in ascending order: `listMaxes` and `numbers`.

If `not Seq.isEmpty numbers`, then it is guaranteed that `not Seq.isEmpty listMaxes` and `Seq.last listMaxes >= Seq.last numbers`.

I would like to implement in F# a function that returns a list of list of integers, whose `List.length` equals `Seq.length listMaxes`, containing the elements of `numbers` divided in lists, where the elements of `listMaxes` limit each group.

For example: called with the arguments

```
listMaxes = seq [ 25; 56; 65; 75; 88 ]
numbers = seq [ 10; 11; 13; 16; 20; 25; 31; 38; 46; 55; 65; 76; 88 ]
```

this function should return

```
[ [10; 11; 13; 16; 20; 25]; [31; 38; 46; 55]; [65]; List.empty; [76; 88] ]
```

I can implement this function, iterating over `numbers` only once:

```
let groupByListMaxes listMaxes numbers = 
    if Seq.isEmpty numbers then
        List.replicate (Seq.length listMaxes) List.empty
    else
        List.ofSeq (seq {
            use nbe = numbers.GetEnumerator ()
            ignore (nbe.MoveNext ())
            for lmax in listMaxes do
                yield List.ofSeq (seq {
                    if nbe.Current <= lmax then
                        yield nbe.Current
                    while nbe.MoveNext () && nbe.Current <= lmax do
                        yield nbe.Current
                })
        })
```

But this code feels unclean, ugly, imperative, and very un-F#-y.

Is there any functional / F#-idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: The function generates runtime errors when you have multiple "maxes" greater than the largest element in numbers, because nbe.Current eventually will called after nbe.MoveNext() returns false.

Comment: Correct observation. The last 3 lines from [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101240/how-to-split-a-sequence-in-f-based-on-another-sequence-in-an-idiomatic-way/43104501#43104501) to add the `extra` lines correct are needed here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done like this with pattern matching and tail recursion:

```
let groupByListMaxes listMaxes numbers =
    let rec inner acc numbers =
        function
        | [] -> acc |> List.rev
        | max::tail ->
            let taken = numbers |> Seq.takeWhile ((>=) max) |> List.ofSeq
            let n = taken |> List.length
            inner (taken::acc) (numbers |> Seq.skip n) tail

    inner [] numbers (listMaxes |> List.ofSeq)
```

**Update**: I also got inspired by `fold` and came up with the following solution that strictly refrains from converting the input sequences.

```
let groupByListMaxes maxes numbers =
    let rec inner (acc, (cur, numbers)) max = 
        match numbers |> Seq.tryHead with
        // Add n to the current list of n's less
        // than the local max
        | Some n when n <= max ->
            let remaining = numbers |> Seq.tail  
            inner (acc, (n::cur, remaining)) max
        // Complete the current list by adding it
        // to the accumulated result and prepare
        // the next list for fold.
        | _ ->
            (List.rev cur)::acc, ([], numbers)

    maxes |> Seq.fold inner ([], ([], numbers)) |> fst |> List.rev
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version based on list interpretation, which is quite functional in style.  You can use `Seq.toList` to convert between them, whenever you want to handle that.  You could also use `Seq.scan` in conjunction with `Seq.partition ((>=) max)` if you want to use only library functions, but beware that it's very very easy to introduce a quadratic complexity in either computation or memory when doing that.

This is linear in both:

```
let splitAt value lst =
    let rec loop l1 = function
        | []                    -> List.rev l1, []
        | h :: t when h > value -> List.rev l1, (h :: t)
        | h :: t                -> loop (h :: l1) t
    loop [] lst

let groupByListMaxes listMaxes numbers =
    let rec loop acc lst = function
        | []     -> List.rev acc
        | h :: t ->
            let out, lst' = splitAt h lst
            loop (out :: acc) lst' t
    loop [] numbers listMaxes
```

Comment: Seq.partition is not part of F# core libraries (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750553/why-is-there-no-seq-partition-in-f)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a better implementation myself. Tips for improvements are still welcome.

Dealing with 2 sequences is really a pain. And I really do want to iterate over `numbers` only once without turning that sequence into a list. But then I realized that turning `listMaxes` (generally the shorter of the sequences) is less costly. That way only 1 sequence remains, and I can use `Seq.fold` over `numbers`.

What should be the state that we want to keep and change while iterating with `Seq.fold` over `numbers`? First, it should definitely include the remaining of the `listMaxes`, yet the previous maxes that we already have surpassed are no longer of interest. Second, the accumulated lists so far, although, like in the other answers, these can be kept in reverse order. More to the point: the state is a couple which has as second element a reversed list of reversed lists of the numbers so far.

```
let groupByListMaxes listMaxes numbers =
    let rec folder state number =
        match state with
            | m :: maxes, _ when number > m ->
                folder (maxes, List.empty :: snd state) number
            | m :: maxes, [] ->
                fst state, List.singleton (List.singleton number)
            | m :: maxes, h :: t ->
                fst state, (number :: h) :: t
            | [], _ ->
                failwith "Guaranteed not to happen"
    let listMaxesList = List.ofSeq listMaxes
    let initialState = listMaxesList, List.empty
    let reversed = snd (Seq.fold folder initialState numbers)
    let temp = List.rev (List.map List.rev reversed)
    let extraLength = List.length listMaxesList - List.length temp
    let extra = List.replicate extraLength List.empty
    List.concat [temp; extra]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I had a very similar problem and I think this is a simple solution:

```
let groupByListMaxes cs xs =
    List.scan (fun (_, xs) c -> List.partition (fun x -> x <= c) xs)
        ([], xs)
        cs
    |> List.skip 1
    |> List.map fst
```